# TokBox OpenTok: Stream Event: streamDestroyed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opentok, tokbox

Experiencing quite weird behavior, 3 out of 5 sessions in average end with this error:

```
{
  "type":"streamDestroyed",
  "cancelable":true,
  "_defaultPrevented":false,
  "reason":"reset",
  "target":
    {
      "_": {},
      "isWebRTC":true,
      "accessAllowed":false,
      "session":null,
      "streamId":"cfe07431-d610-4d2c-8226-55e920f9veq9"
    }
}
```

Can't find mentioned `"reason":"reset"` among reasons listed here:
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamEvent.html

How can I handle this error to silently re-establish the session without reloading or showing errors?